# Why doesnt tab autocomplete to file?

Tags: python, files, auto-completion

I have the file `analysis6_1.py`
So I entered in terminal `python ./` and used tab autocomplete.
Since I wanted to execute `analysis6_1.py` I entered `a` and pressed tab again. However now analysis6_1 is no longer an option and if I enter the file python says that the file does not exist.

I have no clue why that could be. Running UbuntuStudio 14.04 and Python2 with Thunar ((If that helps)). Also see image:
[image: Screenshot of Terminal]

Comment: don't use the ./ Python is the command that executes the file. The system does not want you to type ./ since most likely that file is not set as an executable. Plus is messes with what python expects.

Comment: @Rinzwind Even when not set as executable this should still work. But you have a valid point. I prefer the ./ because this clarifies that I what a file relative to current position instead of /… Even though no program ever will assume that. I thinks its more intuitive. But still this is not the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the spacing of the second column after `python ./`. Those files (except for "analysis3.pyo") each have a space at the start of their filename.

You can rename the files with this:

```
for file in " "*; do 
  mv "$file" "${file#' '}"
done
```

Or if you need to keep the filenames the way they are, you can use autocomplete like so:

`$ python " a`

Press Tab

`$ python " analysis`